# How to create unique CONSTRAINT on relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to create UNIQUE CONSTRAINT to relationship by neo4j(v4.4 or newer) cypher?

Basically, I have FOLDER node and few ITEM nodes, I want to make sure that there is only one CONTAINS relationship from FOLDER to ITEM, even if multiple threads try creating the same relationship.

Note: I found some old threads(dated 2014), but, re-asking this to find if there is a better way of handling it in newer versions.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Which of these do you want to enforce: (1) A `Folder` can have at most one `CONTAINS` relationship (does not matter with which `Item`), or (2) A `Folder` node can have at most one `CONTAINS` relationship to any given `Item` (but it can have many such relationships).

Comment: #2, I want to enforce: A Folder node can have at most one CONTAINS relationship to any given Item (but it can have many such relationships).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create a `CONSTRAINT` that only allows at most one `CONTAINS` relationship between 2 specific `Folder` and `Item` nodes.

As a workaround, you can use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE` whenever you want to create a `CONTAINS`.

**BUT: you must carefully read the [documentation on `MERGE`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge). It is easy to get unexpected results if you do not understand how to use it properly.**

Sample snippet:

```
...
// Assumed: `folder` and `item` are defined earlier in query
MERGE (folder)-[:CONTAINS]->(item)
...
```

Comment: The note about being careful is right on: if any part of that path doesn't exist, you'll get duplicate folder and item nodes. I usually would do something like `merge (folder) merge(item)` before the relationship.

Comment: I have edited my answer to be more blunt about needing to read the documentation for `MERGE`.

Comment: It's an important warning! I like the bold. :D